# Old PEX tube is larger than new

Tags: plumbing

I'm about to tear out a bathroom and want to install some shutoff valves in front of the supply for that room.

I have not used PEX before so before cutting the existing line I bought a small section of 3/4 tube some plugs and clamps to check out the functionality before getting myself in a jam.

The problem I have is that the old PEX is about .020 larger in diameter than the new pex.   I'm afraid I'll cut the old tube and not be able to slip the crimp clamp over the old tube.

Has anyone seen this kind of size related issue?   How have you handled it?

Comment: .020 *what* larger? inches? you should be fine, worst case you can give the end of the pipe some heat to let it squeeze a little.

Answer (score 2):

If the old stuff is grey, its Quest. Pex A is a little bit larger I.D. than regular Pex.

They make change-overs for such cases.